# An unconventional transpose in excel

Tags: excel, offset, transpose

A part of my file consists in this:

```
Et  SF
1   4.4937
1   5.1257
1   5.2018
1   5.3755
1   5.741
1   5.9086
1   6.1399
1   6.2518
2   3.0424
2   3.2744
2   3.883
2   3.9595
2   3.9892
2   4.1603
2   4.2943
2   4.5118
```

And I would like to transpose this way:

```
Et     SF     SF      SF      SF      SF      SF      SF      SF
1   4.4937  5.1257  5.2018  5.3755  5.741   5.9086  6.1399  6.2518
2   3.0424  3.2744  3.883   3.9595  3.9892  4.1603  4.2943  4.5118
```

Is it possible to do this in excel. I tried the option `OFFSET` but I wasn't able to do this.

Comment: In C2: `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)` and fill down, copy-paste values.  Then create a pivot table with the new column as column headers and ColA as row headers

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  And you can use Power Query, available in Excel 2010 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention what did you try. There are many ways:

```
|    | A |    B   |   |  Copy  |        | 4.4937 | 5.1257    | 5.2018 | 5.3755 | 5.741  | 5.9086 | 6.1399 | 6.2518 |
|----|:-:|:------:|:-:|:------:|:------:|--------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 | 1 | 4.4937 | = | =====  | ==|    | 3.0424 | 3.2744    | 3.883  | 3.9595 | 3.9892 | 4.1603 | 4.2943 | 4.5118 |
|  2 | 1 | 5.1257 |   |        |   |    |   A    | Transpose |        |        |        |        |        |        |
|  3 | 1 | 5.2018 |   |        |   |    |   |    |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 4  | 1 | 5.3755 |   |        |   |    |   |    |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 5  | 1 | 5.741  |   |        |   |    |   |    |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 6  | 1 | 5.9086 |   |        |   |    |   |    |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 7  | 1 | 6.1399 |   |        |   |    |   |    |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 8  | 1 | 6.2518 |   |        |   V    |   |    |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 9  | 2 | 3.0424 | > | 3.0424 | 4.4937 | ==|    |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 10 | 2 | 3.2744 | > | 3.2744 | 5.1257 |        |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 11 | 2 | 3.883  | > | 3.883  | 5.2018 |        |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 12 | 2 | 3.9595 | > | 3.9595 | 5.3755 |        |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 13 | 2 | 3.9892 | > | 3.9892 | 5.741  |        |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 14 | 2 | 4.1603 | > | 4.1603 | 5.9086 |        |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 15 | 2 | 4.2943 | > | 4.2943 | 6.1399 |        |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 16 | 2 | 4.5118 | > | 4.5118 | 6.2518 |        |           |        |        |        |        |        |        |
```

Just copy the first section (1) at the right side of the second section (2). Copy the complete selection and paste transposed.

If you want to just make though a formula on the same sheet:

```
|    |  A |    B   | C | D |              E              | F                           | G                           | H   | I | J | K | L | M |
|----|:--:|:------:|:-:|:-:|:---------------------------:|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|-----|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1  | Et | SF     |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 2  | 1  | 4.4937 |   | 1 | =INDIRECT("B" & COLUMN()-3) | =INDIRECT("B" & COLUMN()-3) | =INDIRECT("B" & COLUMN()-3) | ... |   |   |   |   |   |
| 3  | 1  | 5.1257 |   | 2 | =INDIRECT("B" & COLUMN()+5) | =INDIRECT("B" & COLUMN()+5) | =INDIRECT("B" & COLUMN()+5) | ... |   |   |   |   |   |
| 4  | 1  | 5.2018 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 5  | 1  | 5.3755 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 6  | 1  | 5.741  |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 7  | 1  | 5.9086 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 8  | 1  | 6.1399 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9  | 1  | 6.2518 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 10 | 2  | 3.0424 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 11 | 2  | 3.2744 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 12 | 2  | 3.883  |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 13 | 2  | 3.9595 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 14 | 2  | 3.9892 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 15 | 2  | 4.1603 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 16 | 2  | 4.2943 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
| 17 | 2  | 4.5118 |   |   |                             |                             |                             |     |   |   |   |   |   |
```

Hope it helps!